# Is fiber to computer(without the use of any other cables in between) possible?? Are any further developments getting carried out towards this goal?

Tags: network, networking, lan, cable, data

All of us know well that the **fiber to home(FTTH)** connections are a trend nowadays. Every nation is planning to replace the existing metal wires with optical fiber cables. But we also see that the fiber is only used till the networking device and not the client nodes like PC or laptop. LAN cables made up of copper wires are used for this purpose. So, is there any possibility to directly link our devices through optical fiber cables with networking devices replacing the metal LAN cables and is there any ongoing effort being carried out to eliminate this need of LAN cables and insert optical fiber cables directly into the client machines like our home PCs or laptops?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

> we also see that the fiber is only used till the networking device and not the client nodes like PC or laptop.

That isn't really true. Technically, running *fiber to the desktop* isn't a problem. However, fiber cables are very delicate and deploying fiber when there's copper you can use is an expensive luxury.

> LAN cables made up of copper wires

Technically, there is no such a thing as a "LAN cable". Patch cables used for LAN connections can be twisted pair or fiber (or coax, potentially).

Practically all higher-grade network devices, servers, ... feature SFP ports at least optionally. You can add an SFP NIC into any desktop, a laptop would likely require an external adapter. Those SFP ports can be fitted with optical transceivers in a matter of seconds. Fiber transceivers are readily available for any common speed from 100 Mbit/s (100BASE-FX) to 400 Gbit/s (e.g. 400GBASE-SR8).